# Group cohomology as a right derived functor

Tags: homological-algebra, group-cohomology

In [this Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_cohomology), it says that group cohomology can be defined as right derived functor of $F$, where $F(M)=M^G$. There are two different equivalent definition in the page, by explicit cochains and Ext functor.

So I just wonder how can I show the first definition is equivalent to the other two? Thanks!

Comment: The fixed points functor is representable; it's $\text{Hom}(1, M)$ where $1$ denotes the trivial representation. So its derived functors are $\text{Ext}^k(1, M)$. You can get the cocycle description by writing down a particular resolution of $1$ called the bar resolution.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thanks. So why the fixed points functor is representable? Could you please give me some reference?

Comment: You can just directly verify this. You can probably find a discussion of this in any text that covers group cohomology.