# Group Cohomology as a Derived Functor

Tags: commutative-algebra, category-theory, group-cohomology, derived-functors

Let $G$ be a (finite, say) group acting on module $M$. I've been trying to understand how the (standard?) construction of group cohomology $H^i(G,M)$ given [by wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_cohomology#:%7E:text=2.1,Cochain%20complexes) relates to the general definition of a right derived functor [in wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derived_functor#:%7E:text=Motivation-,2,Construction%20and%20first%20properties,-3). The former defines the cochain complex made out of groups of the form:
$$C^n(G,M) = \{ \text{ functions from $G^n$ to $M \}$ }.$$
Whereas the latter defines a cochain complex
$$0 \rightarrow F(I^1) \rightarrow F(I^2) \rightarrow \cdots$$
Where $0 \rightarrow M \rightarrow I^0 \rightarrow I^1 \rightarrow \cdots$ form an injective resolution of $M$ and where $F$ is the functor on $G$-modules given by $F(N) = N^G = $ $G$-invariant elements of $N$. In both cases taking cohomology of the complex gives $H^n(G,M)$. (At least, that's my understanding.)

**Question:** It seems like $C^n(G,M)$ is **not** of the form $F(I^\bullet)$, is that correct? Specifically, it seems like the elements of $C^n(G,M)$ couldn't be the image of $F$ on any module, because they aren't $G$-invariant. (I am assuming the action of $G$ on $C^n(G,M)$ is the one induced by $G$'s action on the image, $M$.)

Is this simply a case of multiple complexes having the same cohomology, and the $C^n(G,M)$ complex being easier to compute than the one coming directly from the definition of a derived functor? Or am I missing something and actually $C^n(G,M) = F(I^n)$ holds?

P.S. Later on in that first wikipedia page they note $H^n(G,M) = \mathrm{Ext}^n_{\mathbb Z[G]}(G,M)$ and explicitly construct it as a derived functor ([see also](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1573092/group-cohomology-as-a-right-derived-functor)). But that seems to be a 3rd distinct complex because they avoid using an injective sequence for $M$ when building it.

Comment: The cleanest to see group cohomology as a derived functor is through “Ext theory”. This is because Ext groups can be computed in two ways: either a projective resolution of the first argument, or an injective resolution of the second one.

Comment: It is very frequently the case in homological algebra that different (co)chain complexes have the same cohomology and that this cohomology is some derived functor that one is after. Injective resolutions are nice for abstract reasoning, but (at least in the case of group cohomology) not that nice for doing actual computations. Taking the standard projective resolution of $\Bbb Z$ as a $\Bbb Z[G]$-module, we end up with formulas that are amenable to computations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in the comments, the cochain complex that computes group cohomology in terms of cocycles comes from a different source than an injective resolution of $M$.

As to your actual question, the $G$ action on $C^n(G,M)$ is a red herring. You should think of $F$ as a functor to abelian groups, as the trivial action doesn't carry information (one typically doesn't consider the group cohomology groups as $G$-modules either, which one should if we consider $F$ as a functor to $G$-modules)

So your argument does not show that an injective resolution $I$ with $F(I^\bullet)=C^n(G,M)$ does not exist. You can't just take any action on $C^n(G,M)$ and say that the elements are not invariant.
After all, as I explained, there is no natural action on $F(I^*)$. You might try to argue that there is the trivial action, but the trivial action is defined for *every* abelian group. Just because we can embed abelian groups to $G$-modules via considering the trivial $G$-action does not mean that every abelian group should always be considered a $G$-module.

Nonetheless, it is true that generally $C^\bullet(G,M)$ is not of the form $F(I^\bullet)$ for any injective resolution $M \to I^\bullet$. To prove this, let $G$ be the trivial group, then $F$ is just isomorphic the identity functor. Thus, if $C^\bullet(G,M)$ was of the form $F(I^\bullet)$, then $C^n(G,M)$ would itself need to be injective for $n\geq 1$. But taking e.g. $M=\Bbb Z$ and considering $n=1$ shows that this is generally not the case.

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed explanation. Your point about the action of G on $C^n(G,M)$ makes total sense. I also found yet another definition of the group cohomology in Neukirch's Cohomology of Number Fields and there the action of G on $\varphi : G \rightarrow M$ (for instance) is $(\sigma_1 \varphi)(\sigma_2) = \sigma_1 (\varphi ( \sigma_1^{-1} \sigma_2))$. So that's an example of a reasonable alternative action to the one I was assuming.